# Rails 3.2.13 Adding fields via jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am currently using rails 3.2.13 and ruby 1.9.3.

I am trying to upload multiple image attachment via a file attachment field.So far, i am able to upload a single file and display the images successfully.

There is this **add_object_link** function at _form.html.erb to create additional file attachment fields but it does not appear or create upon trigger.

model/album.rb

```
    attr_accessible :name, :photos_attributes, :gcategory_id
    has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, :allow_destroy => true
```

model/photo.rb

```
    belongs_to :album
```

view/album/_form.html.erb

```
    <%= render :partial => 'layouts/error_messages', :locals => { :c => @album } %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :gcategory_id %>
      <br />
      <%= f.collection_select :gcategory_id, Gcategory.all, :id, :name %>
    <p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :name, { :class => 'title' } %>
    </p>
    <div class="album_photos">
      <%= render :partial => 'album_photo', :collection => @album.photos %>
    </div>
    <div id="photos">
      <% if @album.new_record? %>
        <%= render :partial => 'photo', :locals => { :form => f, :photo =>          @album.photos.build } %>
      <% else %>
        <% @album.photos.each do |photo| %>
            <%= image_tag photo.data.url(:small) %>
        <% end %>
     <% end %>
    </div>
    <%= add_object_link("New Photo", f, @album.photos.build, "photo", "#photos") %>
   <p>
     <%= f.submit %>
   </p>
```

view/album/_photo.html.erb

```
   <div class="photo">
      <p>
        <%= form.fields_for :photos, photo, :multiple => true, :child_index =>  (photo.new_record? ? "index_to_replace_with_js" : nil) do |photo_form| %>    
          <%= photo_form.file_field :data %>
          <%= link_to_function "delete", "remove_field($(this), ('.photo'))" %><br/>
        <% end %>
      </p>
    </div>
```

view/album/_album)photo.html.erb

```
    <% unless album_photo.new_record? %>
      <%= image_tag(album_photo.data.url(:small),:multiple => true, :alt => '') %>
      <%= check_box_tag "photo_ids[]", album_photo.id %>
    <% end rescue nil %>
```

helpers/albums_helper.rb

```
    def add_object_link(name, form, object, partial, where)
  html = render(:partial => partial, :locals => { :form => form}, :object => object)
  link_to_function name, %{
    var new_object_id = new Date().getTime() ;
    var html = jQuery(#{js html}.replace(/index_to_replace_with_js/g, new_object_id)).hide();
    html.appendTo(jQuery("#{where}")).slideDown('slow');
  }
end

def js(data)
  if data.respond_to? :to_json
    data.to_json
  else
    data.inspect.to_json
  end
end
```

controllers/albums_controller.rb

```
      def new
        @album = Album.new
        3.times { @album.photos.build }
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
        format.xml  { render :xml => @album }
       end
     end
```

There is no errors message shown and able to upload a single file. I can't find the reason why the add_object_link in the form is not creating additional file attachment field.

Thank in advance for any help.